# i cant use file_exists for uploading script

Tags: php, file-upload, file-exists

```
<?php
ini_set('post_max_size', '40M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '40M');

if (isset($_POST['do']) and $_POST['do'] == 'upload') {
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$date = "[".date("d-m-Y_H-i")."]";
$temp = explode(".", $filename);
$new_filename = $temp[0] . ''/*you can put any thing that you want before the [] in the 2 singels*/ . $date . '.' . end($temp);
$f_folder = "uploads" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$_POST['user']. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $new_filename;
$username = $_POST['user'];

echo $username."<br>";

if (file_exists("uploads" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$_POST['user'] == true)){
    if (empty($filename)) {
    echo "choose file please";
    } else {
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $f_folder);
    echo "file is uploaded in " . $f_folder;
    }
    
}else{
    echo "error";
};


echo "<hr>";
echo "
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' >
File Path : <input type='file' name='file' />
<br>
username : <input type='text' name='user' />
<br>
<input type='submit' name='do' value='upload' />
</form>";
?>`
```

this gives me nothing
i want to check if their is a `file name = $_POST['user']`
or is there any better way to create a folder with name `($_POST['user'])` if it does not exist?
and put the uploaded file in it
I know that the code is not clean, but I am still beginner

**UPDATE**

I think that this idea is not easy for beginner maybe later thank you all

Comment: Please re-indent your script properly and you will find why it currently results in an `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file`

Comment: and btw: your two `ini_set`s have no effect. Both `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` are `PHP_INI_PERDIR` and the "effect" already took place before the script is executed. see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php and http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code:

```
if (file_exists("uploads" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$_POST['user'] == true)){
```

should be:

```
if (file_exists("uploads" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$_POST['user']) == true){
```

The `== true` isn't needed though.

Comment: i want to check if their is a folder name = $_POST['user']

Comment: still no output at all the page

Comment: If you get a blank page, enable error reporting. You're working in the dark here...